# Using SSH tunneling to only allow access to certain mobile device

Tags: ssh, security

I need a way for our app that sends data from a phone to a server and to a database
to only allow certain mobile devices to accept data from.
I searched ip filtering but the ip addresses of phones change all the time. and mac address filtering isn't as secure. people recommended SSH tunneling but I can only find scenarios for desktop and not for mobile

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure who told you about using an SSH tunnel. That's practical if you are connecting two servers together, or a client you control and a server.

The only way that works in the current world is by having the customer connect to your server. The server generates a unique session identifier (such as a UUID, it has to be large enough and best possible randomness to be secure) and sends that to the user's phone. That's often called a cookie.

Then each time the phone wants to access your server, it sends that cookie which identifies the phone as an allowed user.

Of course, all the communications have to happen encrypted (TLS 1.2 or better).

---

Note that there is also VPN. This is similar to SSH, but opens a connection through which other safe connections can be mode. It really will depend on your app., personally I would not recommend VPN as it adds another layer which is likely to fail *in strange ways* (i.e. the rest of your app. won't exactly know why it's failing to connect, receive data, etc.).